# Generalizing the Abel Theorem to higher order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $$y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=g(t)$$ then By the Abel theorem wronskian equals to :

$$W= c e^{\int p(t)dt}$$

Now We want to generalise this to a 3rd order differential equation where :

$$y'''+p_1(t)y''+p_2(t)y'+p_3(t)y=0$$

And The book follows the procedure below, I had no idea what is meant would be grateful if someone manages to explain :

> First write down $W'$. Then, substitute for $y_1''',y_2''' \ and \ y_3'''$ from the differential equation; multiply the first row by $p_3$, multiply the second row by $p_2$ and add these to the last row to obtain : $$W'= -p_1(t)W$$

After this point I believe I can show the rest. However I didn't understand any word from the sentence above. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wronskian of functions $f_1(x), f_2(x), \cdots, f_n(x)$ is defined as
$$
W=\begin{vmatrix}
f_1(x) & f_2(x) &  \cdots &f_n(x)\\
f_1'(x) & f_2'(x) & \cdots &f_n'(x)\\
f_1''(x) & f_2''(x) & \cdots &f_n''(x)\\
\vdots\\
f_1^{(n-1)}(x) & f_2^{(n-1)}(x) & \cdots &f_n^{(n-1)}(x)
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Now suppose you have a differential equation
$$
y^{(n)}=p_1(x) y^{(n-1)}+\cdots + p_{n-1}(x)y+p_n(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}p_{n-m}(x)y^{(m)}
$$
with the convention that $y^{(0)}=1$.
Abel's theorem is all about calculating the Wronskian of the $n$ solutions of the above ODE, say $y_1,\cdots, y_n$. So let's just do that... First note that (prove it)
$$W'=\begin{vmatrix}
y_1 & y_2 &  \cdots &y_n\\
y_1' & y_2' & \cdots &y_n'\\
y_1'' & y_2'' & \cdots &y_n''\\
\vdots\\
y_1^{(n-2)} & y_2^{(n-2)} & \cdots &y_n^{(n-2)}\\
y_1^{(n)} & y_2^{(n)} & \cdots &y_n^{(n)}
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
y_1 & y_2 &  \cdots &y_n\\
y_1' & y_2' & \cdots &y_n'\\
y_1'' & y_2'' & \cdots &y_n''\\
\vdots\\
y_1^{(n-2)} & y_2^{(n-2)} & \cdots &y_n^{(n-2)}\\
\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}p_{n-m}y_1^{(m)} & \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}p_{n-m}y_2^{(m)} & \cdots &\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}p_{n-m}y_n^{(m)}
\end{vmatrix}$$
where the second equality comes from the differential equation. Now by using the properties of determinant (specifically its multi-linearily)
$$
W'=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}p_{n-m}
\begin{vmatrix}
y_1 & y_2 &  \cdots &y_n\\
y_1' & y_2' & \cdots &y_n'\\
y_1'' & y_2'' & \cdots &y_n''\\
\vdots\\
y_1^{(n-2)} & y_2^{(n-2)} & \cdots &y_n^{(n-2)}
\\
y_1^{(m)} & y_2^{(m)} & \cdots &y_n^{(m)}
\end{vmatrix}=
p_{1}W
$$
I leave it to you to figure out how each equality in the above identity came to be. Now we have found that $W'=p_1(x)W$ which has a easy solution $W=c\int p_1(t)dt$. QED.

If this proof seems abstract to you, or if you are not familiar with properties of determinants, try proving each step in the above proof with the properties of  $3\times 3$ determinants that you know.